# how to load loader service after service call completed in Angular15

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular15. I need help I struck with method loading service.

**Scenario:** Based on the requirement we wrote two services. First one for “loading”. This will hide the background while any operation performing. Second service is to update the records on Database.

Now by using these two methods. We are performing update operations in our application. While performing update operation to restrict the user we are using loader service displaying loading screen.

**Problem:** Updating service and loader service are working fine individually. But when we try to work with two services, we are facing issue.

The issue is before completing updating the loading service got executed. User unable to see the loader at the time of updating.

How to show the loading bar while performing update operation.

**UpdateUser.component.ts**

```
//Update value method
public updateValue(): void {
//update service method to update the userdata.
      this.userUpdateService.update(UserUpdateData).subscribe(() => {
        if (loadData) {
          this.getUpdatedData();
        }
      });
  }


updateUser()
{
//to show the loader
      this.loadingService.view();
//Calling Update value
this. updateValue();
//to hide the loader
this.loadingService.hide();
}
```

we tried to call loaders as below.

```
//Update value method
public updateValue(): void {
this.loadingService.view();
//update service method to update the userdata.
      this.userUpdateService.update(UserUpdateData).subscribe(() => {
        if (loadData) {
          this.getUpdatedData();
this.loadingService.hide();
        }
      });

this.loadingService.hide();
  }
```

Here we observed that the hide() method called before completing update service call. I want to know how to wait or find the update service execution completed.

Thank you

Comment: Confusing: why do you call `view()` and `hide()` both in `updateUser()` and `updateValue()`? Anyway, in `updateValue()` you should drop the 2nd call to `hide()` and instead do `... if (loadData) { ... } else { hide(); } ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the loadingService is being executed prematurely due to its placement after the call to userUpdateService, because of asynchronous operations.

my suggestion solutin:

```
    public updateValue(): void {
  
  this.loadingService.view();

  this.userUpdateService.update(UserUpdateData).subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
      if (response.loadData) {
        this.getUpdatedData(); 
      }

      this.loadingService.hide();
    },
    error: (error) => {
                this.loadingService.hide();
    }
  });
}
```